# jsPdf addSvgAsImage, SVG image is not in the saved pdf addSvgAsImage

Tags: javascript, svg, jspdf

i am using Method addSvgAsImage and then pdf.save("test.pdf"),
but i am getting empty pdf, without any errors.

```
this.doc = new jsPDF();
this.doc.addSvgAsImage(this.svgAsString(text),80,40,80,80);
this.doc.save('test.pdf');

svg=<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="256" height="256">
 <rect x="0" y="0" width="256" height="256" style="fill:#ffffff;shape-rendering:crispEdges;"/>
```

Could anyone help me please ? Thanks.

Comment: surprised to see its been almost 2 years and no one has answered to this. Facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's because addSvgAsImage() is asynchronous, try to put doc.save() into small setTimeout().

> setTimeout(() => this.doc.save('test.pdf'), 500);